# What type of lawyer (criminal, civil, family, etc.) would I need to help me deal with issues of academic misconduct?

Tags: university, academic-life, policy, law

What can stop a university from doing whatever they want and screwing students over in terms of accusing them **unfairly** of cheating, plagiarism, or a misunderstanding of professor authorization of essay re-submission in a second class? Also trying to take a student's degree or credit away after the course is completed/graduated with little evidence and no proof of circumstantial evidence that truly happened at the time of the incident? I ask this since they are private and go by their own rules and apparently there is no standard policy for how all universities are supposed to deal with issues. There are a lot of cases where businesses "screw people over".

This is in St. Catharines, Ontario, Canada.

Thanks.

Comment: We can't answer if you don't specify the country, what you mean by "screwing students over" and what do you mean by "type of lawyer".

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about what your "issues of academic misconduct" entail?  It's not really possible to provide any advice with this level of information.

Comment: You could try asking on Law SE.  Also, you can try emailing question@nycourts.gov.  I sent them a question once and they answered it in less than 24 hours.  What you would do, is describe the situation briefly, and ask what recourse you have.  If there's a particular law or regulation you could use (such as, in New York, Article 78), then you'd have something you could use in google or in a lawyer database search box.

Comment: Also, you are welcome to describe the particular situation here.  But if you do, I advise using a different, more anonymous, username.

Comment: I advise you to start fresh, with a different username, and post a link to your institution's policy.  The key, really, is to go by *their* policy to see what hoops they offer to students who have been accused of something.

Comment: My university doesn't have a policy on it. That's why I'm asking on here. I've edited the description.

Comment: @JPhills I find it inconceivable that your university does not have any policy regarding academic misconduct.

Comment: https://brocku.ca/webfm_send/28409

They have a general guideline policy, but nothing regarding my question.

Comment: I agree with @aparente001 that this seems a better question to ask in Law SE, and that you might wish to start over with your question. This is a stressful situation, but the phrasing of your question probably does not incline many of the academic faculty here to support your cause. If this were even the appropriate SE to post your question to, I think we would need more transparent details about your university and the specifics of your situation.

Comment: @NMJD - I'd like to clarify that we agree on the proposal to ask on SE Law, and to make a fresh start with your question here, but with an anonymous user name, so you can explain your situation in more detail.  We are not in agreement on the second part of your comment.  I have no reason to think anything negative based on your question.

Comment: I don't know why you're concerned about possible job loss. //  "Since they are private and go by their own rules and apparently there is no standard policy for how all universities are supposed to deal with issues" - even if they were public, they would still have to set their own rules.  I think that all colleges and universities are probably required to *have* a policy, in order to maintain their accreditation. // Have you spoken with the Ombudsman?

Comment: I'm concerned about job loss because I'm afraid if the degree is taken away, then my employment contract could be void by not meeting all the requirements since I now have a job in my field (this is in government, but I'm sure private companies wouldn't be pleased if they find out.  That goes as well for the risk and process of applying to new jobs. That's all if an employer were to find out between the times of losing the degree and going through another course that I would have to sign up for and complete, which could take up to four+ months depending on the next course registration date....

Comment: @aparente001 That's fine. I think the language and lack of details originally present would not incline many faculty to believe that the student did not, accidentally or not, commit plaigerism or academically dishonest conduct. That's my opinion, and it won't be everyone's.

Comment: @NMJD I'm saying I might have committed misconduct. Due to the professor's negligence and not looking into it/enforcing it/educating me on it at the time on this type of misconduct, therefore passing me, could the professor retroactively act on it even though I've entered the next year's/semester's courses? Or even if enough time has passed that I graduate? I mean, that seems unfair to the student in terms of their academic planning, graduation planning, job acquisition planning, etc. It could really "screw them over", especially if it was a matter of not knowing and/or misunderstanding.

Comment: @aparente001 I've also edited the question for your grammatical needs.

Comment: @JPhills ah I see. As jakebeal explains in his answer, there is a procedure for how academic misconduct cases are handled. At most universities, there is a variety of potential outcomes, one of which is failing the class. However, at most (not all) universities this is usually an extreme example and reserved for repeat offenses. If this is your first time with an academic misconduct report, it seems very likely that, even if you were found to be guilty of the offense, there would be a lesser repercussion (such as an F on the individual assignment).

Comment: @NMJD If a student or myself has graduated I'm also afraid of them revoking the degree from under my nose if they feel I haven't responded to their reach out in a sufficient amount of time when they failed to reach me by my current contact info since it has changed since I graduated. I just don't know how they'd proceed if the student graduated and they have no way to contact the student. Since students are contacted through their student email address, which I have no access to anymore

Comment: Have you spoken with the Ombudsman? // Also, have you taken a look at http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/81773/32436?

Comment: Calling the professor "negligent" in failing to catch and punish you is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Why is that a bad idea? If the prof educates the student at the right time then they can maintain the flow and plan for when they intend to graduate and maintain other plans instead of advancing so far and being set back

Comment: @JPhills it is not the responsibility of the professor to educate the student on what constitutes proper academic conduct. Many professors choose to do this and/or explicitly refer students to university policies on academic honesty. The responsibility ultimately lies on students to produce honest work regardless of if the professor assists in that way. As for your concern of degree revocation: I would say that would be a severe and unlikely consequence, but it's possible. I would expect that to only occur in cases where a student committed multiple, extreme, obviously-intentional offenses.

Comment: @NMJD It says in my school's academic integrity policy that it is the professor's responsibility to (as well as the student's) to be familiar with academic integrity but also says professors should make sure the guidelines for academic integrity in their class are clearly defined and understood by students and academic integrity cases are sometimes the result of a lack of understanding from the student. https://brocku.ca/webfm_send/28409 section 6.6 paragraph 5 and section 6.4

Comment: @JPhills 6.4a states students bear independent responsibility for knowing the guidelines as well.  A professor could satisfy their responsibility simply by announcing or putting on the syllabus "Your work must obey the university guidelines for academic honesty". Then the onus lies on the student to know what those guidelines require. As 6.6 says: "it is required that all students exercise due diligence toward the understanding and execution of all appropriate academic  guidelines" According to 6.6, if what you say is true you clearly have a case meriting educative action at the most.

Comment: @NMJD  https://brocku.ca/webfm_send/4713 this is the form we sometimes attach to essays and assignments. It was confusing because on this form it doesn't say anything about getting permission for duplicate submissions **in writing**...just permission. So you would think if a student hands in a paper citing sources from textbooks used in a different course taken last year, either a red flag should go up or we move on. The prof should have immediately looked into the possibility that the first year version of the essay exists with the TA and remedy the situation/misunderstanding....

Comment: @NMJD ...(if there is one) or not do anything, move forward and forever hold his peace. If they don't exist there's nothing they can prove anyway. I'm just saying if they do exist in their email inboxes or kept in some other location.

Answer (score 16):

Now that you've supplied sufficient information, the answer to your question seems fairly clearly spelled out [within the university's own policy documents](https://brocku.ca/webfm_send/28409):

- Section 6.6 shows that the decision-making process is not just a single professor "screwing you over," but rather:

  > a determination of academic misconduct shall be decided
  > by the Department Chair/Program Director based on a discussion between the student, the
  > instructor, and the Department Chair/Program Director, as well as a review of the evidence
- At some point, it leaves the department and ends up in the hands of a Dean, who also meets with the students. The full details of the process are spelled out in Section 7.
- If the student is unhappy, they have a right to appeal to a Senate Student Appeals Board (Section 8), which seems a peer body rather than a faculty body.  The full details of that process are spelled out in another linked document.

This looks like a pretty typical set of checks and balances: the individual professor is involved, but the key decision-making is not done by that professor or even within the department, and the faculty is in turn checked by appeals to a body of students.

Now, if your professor, the department head, the involved dean, and the student board are all convinced that you are guilty, you've got a more serious problem on your hands. Getting outside legal help *might* be warranted, but based on what you've written here, it seems like it's also quite plausible that you've either committed an offense and don't understand why it's an offense, or else that you've done yourself a disservice in the process by alienating people who might otherwise have helped.

Comment: This is a great answer. +1 for the clearly deciphering the provided policies, and for the last sentence which I agree with but could not have put so diplomatically.

Comment: In general, legal help might be warranted if a university did not follow their own stated policy in making a determination of academic misconduct and applying penalties.

Comment: My issue is an issue of a misunderstanding of unauthorized resubmission of work where I thought I had authorization from the professor. I recently graduated and there was no policy outlining a situation like this in the event that something is discovered after the fact. I also asking, If they don't follow their own procedure, what could legally happen to the university then?

Comment: @JPhills It is pointless to ask questions about hypotheticals, when so much is situation-dependent. You are not currently the subject of a misconduct investigation; we cannot speculate about what _might_ happen if you were.

Comment: If two trains are predicted moving towards each other on the same track, why wait until they actually crash until you do something about it?

Comment: It's good to game these things out so that one would know what to do in these situations. Because they are a big deal in terms of financial, time, and even a job loss to the student.

Comment: @ff524 it's also entirely possible that a university _did_ follow their own policy yet ended up reaching an unreasonable decision. In which case it's conceivable that a lawsuit will force them to reverse the decision. Hypothetically speaking, of course. But you are right that them not following their policy would make the lawsuit more likely to succeed.

Comment: @JPhills: The flip side of that approach: https://xkcd.com/761/

Comment: @JPhills From what you've said so far, it seems to me that you are skipping ahead a few steps. First, see if the university actually considers it a significant issue at all. If they do care, then follows the procedure: calm yourself down, read it carefully and understand it, and begin with the assumption that they're not out to get you. Only if that all goes wrong would it be normally time to get a lawyer involved.

Comment: Reading through this, and taking a few things into account....I cannot tell if this is a serious post, or an elaborate trolling.  First is the question itself, which is formatted as if it was posted from a phone, or just not formatted at all.  Second is the lack of a clear question in and of itself.  And third is the inclusion of hypothetical questions in response to others' comments.   Those, as well as a user filing a question about using legal aid against a college, with an easily identifiable username.....

Comment: @NZKshatriya Not sure what's wrong with the question formatting...and it's a legit question for dealing with complicated matters of misconduct that the university may or may not take proper procedures to deal with effectively that protects the student, and not just the lazy interests of the university. I have better things to do than to troll on this site. This is a legit concern I have in case a prof ever mistakenly accuses me or another student of misconduct after the course may or may not be over in case of confusion/negligence on the university's part.

Comment: @NZKshatriya People can make mistakes and students have in fact sued their schools before for issues related to accusations of academic misconduct. Look it up. And I'm not sure what my choice of username has to do with anything either.

Comment: @JPhills If you have emails to/from the professor where he communicates what you had believed to be permission to resubmit your work, those would be valuable for you in your proceedings. You might not have those, but if you ever find yourself in similar circumstances in the future, it might be a good idea to ensure you ask/are granted permission over email, that way you have the permission in writing and the professor could not forget and/or dispute it.

Comment: @JPhills  Usually, when one goes about asking about what they should do in these situations, they do so using a username that doesn't easily tie back to a real individual.  Reason I am pointing this out is that who knows if said university pays attention to certain sites in order to be ready for any possibly legal issues with students/employees.

Comment: @NZKshatriya I understand. This isn't my real name lol

Comment: AH, that makes more sense.......Im likely a bit stressed due to holidays and just being picky on questions.  >.,

Comment: @JPhills - Thank you for the reassurance.  That has been bothering me since I first saw your question.

Answer (score 7):

Because the dispute does not involve criminal charges, is between two parties, and does not involve criminal or family law, you want a civil lawyer. Specifically, you seem to be accusing the university of [civil tort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tort).

Universities tend to have very good (read: expensive) lawyers protecting them (and their endowments). You would need an equally good (read: expensive) lawyer to be able to have a go at them.

Whether you will find a civil lawyer willing to take you on without a hefty retainer (at least $10,000 in my neck of the woods if not much more) is an entirely different matter.

Comment: University counsel often has better things to do. And I knew a lawyer who represented students (this university allowed the retention of counsel for certain academic misconduct hearings) and they were *not* in the $10,000 retainer range.

Comment: Counsel for an academic hearing is cheap. Actually suing the university is an entirely different thing and is quite expensive. You do know the difference, don't you?

Comment: I do - they *still* weren't in that range. But I also think it's not likely that "sue the university" is actually the ops path forward

Comment: I agree, it's a fool's errand. But the OP asked what type of lawyer it would take to sue the university and I think my answer is the honest answer -- a civil lawyer -- and if OP wants to be successful, an expensive civil lawyer. At even $200 an hour, $10k is just 50 hours of time - i.e., one week of the lawyer and paralegal's time and those are cheap rates.

Comment: I'm not even sure expensive is justified in that circumstance. Not all university counsel are high-powered badasses, and "let's just make this go away so we can all get on with our jobs" isn't necessarily a 10k retainer task

Comment: Basically, I liked your answer then you overshot. Presumably to help steer the op down a more productive path

Comment: A university will settle if the soup in the cafeteria was too hot. They might settle quickly over sexual harassment. They won't easily settle over an expulsion or degree revocation if all procedures were fulfilled, which is the scenario the OP presents.

Comment: People think lawyers are cheap. They are only cheap if they agree to take you on contingency - which means they think that there are good odds of winning and they can use boilerplate briefs (ie., traffic accidents, medical malpractice).  I don't see the odds here as being good, and thus took contingency off the table.

Comment: I know a number of lawyers who will charge you a reasonable rate (for lawyer values of reasonable) to tell you this is a bad idea and you should stop. I'd suggest such a consultation is way more productive even with lawyers then heading straight to retainers and visions of courtrooms

Comment: Agreed, most lawyers will agree to consult for free -- and they'll likely convince OP to not do it. But that wasn't the question. If they did agree to take it on, it'd be very expensive.

Comment: I'd argue the lawyer most closely "helping her deal with" is the one not convincing her to chase sunk costs with a lawsuit and expensive retainer. Like I said, I think the core of this answer is solid.